# M3DA: What does the acronym mean?

Tags: acronym

is there someone who knows what the acronym "M3DA" ([the M2M-protocol defined by the Mihihni developers](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Mihini/M3DA_Specification)) stands for? I'm just not able to find anything on that, maybe I'm blind - or is there just no fixed meaning behind it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Machine-to-machine](https://medium.com/predict/an-era-of-iot-m2m-communication-protocols-a03c396397a1)?

Comment: It's also what I am guessing but there must be more I think... maybe Machine2Machine M... Data A...?

Answer (score 0):

M3DA: A protocol optimized for the transport of binary M2M data, which is made available in the Mihini project.

M2M + Mihini = 3M
&
DA=data

That's all.